# How can I write this loop in Stata correctly?

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a loop in Stata that will create 19 new variables.

The code that is used to create two of these variables is:

```
generate kode_saksinnhold_1 = 1 if kode_saksinnhold == "1" 
generate kode_saksinnhold_2 = 1 if kode_saksinnhold == "2"
```

And so on for the other 17 variables. I am a newbie to stata and loops and tried this code which gave me the error message "'invalid name"

```
forval i =1/19 {
  generate kode_saksinnhold_`i’ = 1 kode_saksinnhold == "`i’"
}
```

Could someone help explain why this was not correct and suggest the correct way to do it?

Comment: If your goal is a set of indicator variables, then (1) indicators that are 1  or missing are not as useful as indicators that are 1 or 0; (2) the loop is not needed as the -tabulate- command will generate all at once through an option (3) for model fitting purposes factor variable notation gives you indicators on the fly. For indicators read dummies if that is how your tribe talks

Comment: Hi Nick, 
Thanks for your answer. I agree that indicators that are 1 or missing are not as useful, I was thinking that I would change the missing values to 0 after creating the variables. Could you give me an example of what you mean by the tabulate command creating all 19 variables at once? Would this keep the correct values of the variables, meaning kode_saksinnhold_2 = 1 based on the current variable kode_saksinnhold == "2"?

Comment: Update: I got my desired result by destringing the "kode_saksinnhold" variable and then using the tabulate command as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: I agree: first use `destring` (which I wrote first!) in your circumstances.

Comment: See https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099 for an overview of creating indicator variables in Stata.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `if` in your second code block. Try this:

```
forval i = 1/19 {
  generate kode_saksinnhold_`i' = 1 if kode_saksinnhold == "`i'"
}
```

Comment: The right quote may not be the correct character.

Comment: You have caught the second bug but please see my comments on the question. (Upvoted, naturally.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This was actually a typo on my part - the original code does contain an "if" in the second code block.

Comment: As you'll appreciate, we see the code you post here, not the code on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The `generate()` option is documented, but here is a silly example:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 automobile data)

. tab rep78, generate(rep78_)

     Repair |
record 1978 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          1 |          2        2.90        2.90
          2 |          8       11.59       14.49
          3 |         30       43.48       57.97
          4 |         18       26.09       84.06
          5 |         11       15.94      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         69      100.00

. d rep78_*

Variable      Storage   Display    Value
    name         type    format    label      Variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rep78_1         byte    %8.0g                 rep78== 1.0000
rep78_2         byte    %8.0g                 rep78== 2.0000
rep78_3         byte    %8.0g                 rep78== 3.0000
rep78_4         byte    %8.0g                 rep78== 4.0000
rep78_5         byte    %8.0g                 rep78== 5.0000
```

The `generate()` option is accepted for string variables, but if those string variables have numeric content, then `destring` first.

Comment: Hi Nick, 

Thanks for the example. I have done this successfully with the kode_saksinnhold variable that I originally asked about, but just now tried to perform the same operation with a variable called "kode_melder" that has values 1-23. When I run the code "tabulate kode_melder, generate(melder_), stata creates 22 indicator variables instead of 23 (so, melder_1 - melder_22). Do you know why stata is not creating an indicator variable for kode_melder == 23? It occurs at a frequency of 203, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: No idea!  But please: you should not ask new questions in comments. Also, I see you've started asking questions in Statalist. I and some others do what I can with Stata question here, but you're better off asking on Statalist.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip! I will ask over there.